# Tag Enforcement for EC2 - AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tags

I wanted to enforce tags for EC2. Means, without certain tags, it shouldn't allow to launch EC2 instance. I have a solution with IAM Policy, but I don't want this to be with IAM Policy.

Looking for some other way to enforce tags.
Please advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I your account is **part of an AWS organisation** then you're in luck. AWS released a feature called [tag-policies](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-use-tag-policies-to-manage-tags-across-multiple-aws-accounts/) that specifically forces EC2 instances in an organisational unit to require certain tags.

However if your account is standalone (not part of an AWS organisation) then IAM will be the primary tool for controlling user access, so if a permission is set here then it will always be allowed.

There is another options to remove these instances if you are in a stand alone account using AWS Config.

AWS Config has a managed rule of [required-tags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/required-tags.html). Assuming a required rule is not set then a Lambda can be invoked to terminate the instance in question.

Comment: Thanks, my account is a part of AWS Organisation. I tried tag policies, but it doesn't allow me to enforce(prevent launch of EC2). Enforce means shouldn't allow me to launch instance with the required tags. Could you please help.

Comment: Did you look at https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-use-tag-policies-to-manage-tags-across-multiple-aws-accounts/. You select "Prevent Noncompliant Operations" for each tag and select the resource type(s) that apply to the policy.

Comment: you can use below options (1) Deny Users if they are missing required tags for EC2 instances https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-policy-tags-restrict/ along with https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/required-tags.html , You can then setup a CloudWatch rule to monitor your Config rule for compliance changes with a SNS topic as a target (you can subscribe an email address to that SNS topic) https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/monitor-config-with-cloudwatchevents.html

Comment: (2) another way is to create a lambda function that checks all ec2 instances that has no tags that you require. Then emails you via SNS the ec2 instance.

Comment: @mokugo-devops I tried "Prevent Non compliant Operations" too, but it allowed me to launch ec2 instance.. That's what I wonder.  Looks like "Prevent Non compliant Operations" prevents from adding more tags.. Please assist.

Comment: @John Rotenstein any help please

Comment: @user1562991 it is stated `Enforcement has no effect on resources that are created without tags.` so its possible you created the resource without the tag. In which case your only option is IAM to enforce this, there are no other controls I'm afraid.

Comment: @mokugo-devops Thats the concern. I need Enforcement to have effect on resources that are created without tags. It shouldn't allow to create/launch EC2 instances. Need a way to do it except IAM.

Comment: There is no other way outside of tag policies and IAM, could you elaborate on why you need to do it outside of IAM perhaps? :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Polices in AWS Organizations and select Tag policies. be sure to enable it if it isn't enabled prior. then create a policy like this. you can use the given json editor for this.

```
{ 
  "tags": { 
    "User": { 
      "tag_key": { 
        "@@assign": "User" 
      }, 
      "enforced_for": { 
        "@@assign": [ 
          "ec2:instance" 
        ] 
      } 
    }, 
    "Duration": { 
      "tag_key": { 
        "@@assign": "Duration" 
      }, 
      "enforced_for": { 
        "@@assign": [ 
          "ec2:instance" 
        ] 
      } 
    } 
  } 
}
```

In here, I have created a tag policy for User tag and Duration Tag. Once the tag policy is created, make sure to attach it to the target OU/Account.

After this, go to Policies again and select Service control policies (SCPs)
and if it isn't available, make sure to enable it. In there, create a new SCPs policy and add the following policy.

```
{ 
  "Version": "2012-10-17", 
  "Statement": [ 
    { 
      "Sid": "DenyEC2CreationSCP1", 
      "Effect": "Deny", 
      "Action": [ 
        "ec2:RunInstances" 
      ], 
      "Resource": [ 
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*", 
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*" 
      ], 
      "Condition": { 
        "Null": { 
          "aws:RequestTag/User": "true" 
        } 
      } 
    }, 
    { 
      "Sid": "DenyEC2CreationSCP2", 
      "Effect": "Deny", 
      "Action": [ 
        "ec2:RunInstances" 
      ], 
      "Resource": [ 
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*", 
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*" 
      ], 
      "Condition": { 
        "Null": { 
          "aws:RequestTag/Duration": "true" 
        } 
      } 
    } 
  ]
```

In here I have created SCP to enforce previous tag policy. Once the SCPs are created, make sure that you attach it to the target OU/Account.