# How to enforce Tag usage when creating S3 Buckets?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I want to prevent users from creating an S3 bucket when there is not Tag with the key 'project'.
Following policy won't work. It prevents creation in any case

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "DenyCreationWithoutProjectTag",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Action": "s3:CreateBucket",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringNotLike": {
                "aws:RequestTag/project": "*"
            }
        }
    }
]}
```

[Tag Enforcement for EC2 - AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62304705/tag-enforcement-for-ec2-aws)
and
[Enforce tagging for AWS resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65988136/enforce-tagging-for-aws-resources)

did not help.

Comment: CreateBucket does not allow you to indicate tags, so this will never work.

Comment: Okay thanks. Do you see another way to achieve this?

Comment: You could maybe use CloudTrail to react to CreateBucket API requests and verify that a newly-created bucket has been tagged within a certain amount of time. A process that ensures that bucket continue to have project tags is probably better than one that just tests for the tag at creation time anyhow. Maybe investigate AWS Config Managed Rules, or run a process once per day (e.g. simple Lambda) to query for untagged buckets.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Polices in AWS Organizations and select Tag policies. be sure to enable it if it isn't enabled prior. then create a policy like this. you can use the given json editor for this.

```
{ 
  "tags": { 
    "Project": { 
      "tag_key": { 
        "@@assign": "Project" 
      }, 
      "enforced_for": { 
        "@@assign": [ 
          "s3:bucket" 
        ] 
      } 
    } 
  } 
}
```

In here, I have created a tag policy for Project tag. Once the tag policy is created, make sure to attach it to the target OU/Account.

After this, go to Policies again and select Service control policies (SCPs)
and if it isn't available, make sure to enable it. In there, create a new SCPs policy and add the following policy.

```
{ 
  "Version": "2012-10-17", 
  "Statement": [ 
    { 
      "Sid": "DenyS3CreationSCP1", 
      "Effect": "Deny", 
      "Action": [ 
        "s3:CreateBucket" 
      ], 
      "Resource": "*", 
      "Condition": { 
        "Null": { 
          "aws:RequestTag/Project": "true" 
        } 
      } 
    } 
  ] 
}
```

In here I have created SCP to enforce previous tag policy. Once the SCPs are created, make sure that you attach it to the target OU/Account.

Comment: The `s3:CreateBucket` action does not support the `aws:RequestTag` condition key. This answer is incorrect.

Comment: This method work. I suggest you to do an implementation and see the results.